# React Navigation - navigate and set history for the back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react-native app using react-navigation@5.1

I have a TabNavigator (nested inside a stack navigator) with multiple tabs. Each tab contains another StackNavigator. One of these tab stacks has a list screen and a details screen.

The app is setup to receive push notifications when the app is in the background. When a user presses a push notification it opens the app and navigates them to the details/:id screen.

The problem is, if the user was not already on the list screen the back button does not have the proper history and does not appear.

How would I go about ensuring that the back button for the details screen always takes the user to the list screen?

Here is a depiction of my nested navigators

```
<NavigationContainer>
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="loading">
    <Stack.Screen name="auth">
    <Stack.Screen name="app">
      <Tabs.Navigator>
         <Tabs.Screen name="community">
           <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="list">.  <- list
              <Stack.Screen name="detail"> <- detail
           </Stack.Navigator>
         </Tabs.Screen>
         <Tabs.Screen name="profile">
           <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.screen name="edit">  <- user may already be on this screen
              ...
           </Stack.Navigator>
         </Tabs.Screen>
         ... more tabs and stacks
    </Stack.Screen>
 </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Any time a user receives a push notification they will already be on one of the Stack Navigators inside the Tab Navigator. Again, the issue is the user might be on the edit screen inside the profile tab. I need to redirect them to the detail screen of the community tab but ensure the history contains the list screen for the back functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the route history using the reset action. This should get you started:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(state => {
  // Assuming you only have the current screen in state.routes
  const routes = [{name: 'home-or-wherever'}, ...state.routes];

  return CommonActions.reset({
    ...state,
    routes,
    index: routes.length - 1,
  });
});
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

Comment: I have been messing with `CommonActions.reset` I keep getting this error though: `Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

Comment: My bad I was not returning CommonActions.reset. Now I am getting the following error: `The Action RESET .... was not handled by any navigator. I think this is because they are nested navigators?

Comment: Yes, nesting is such a pain most of the the time. You can try a root navigator ref, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop. It's been a while since I've had that exact issue, and it's all coming back like a bad dream!  Worth reading into this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335

Comment: Yes indeed... thanks, ill look through the docs again, I have done a bunch of digging but haven't gotten too far with this... I updated the post to include a depiction of my navigator layout

Comment: Perhaps this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335#issuecomment-550340067  Let me know results, curious if that works. I'd try to update it to createRef syntax if it does.

Comment: Nope, no luck there... since I know the back button should always be visible and always take me to the list screen I have added the headerLeft option to that screen. headerLeft is a HeaderBackButton with an onPress utilizing the dispatch and reset code you shared. Its working but seems like there should be a better way. Im going to leave the question open for a day or 2 but ill accept your answer if no one else comes up with anything better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using CommonActions.reset() with nested stack navigator you can include the state and routes of nested navigators to achieve the desired functionality--perhaps this is what you're after?

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: "community",
        state: {
          index: 1,
          routes: [
            { name: "list"},
            { name: "detail" },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```